# value of type 'NSOpenPanel' has no member 'allowedContentTypes'

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

If a try to set the `allowedContentTypes` for an `NSOpenPanel`, I get always the message that this isn't a member. I cannot use the `openPanel.allowedFileTypes` because it is deprecated.
I didn't change any setting for the project. It was defined primary as an empty object, and then a added a macOS target
In the source I only `import Cocoa`

See code:

```
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.title = "SelectImageTitle"
    openPanel.prompt = "SelectImagePrompt"
    openPanel.nameFieldLabel = "SelectImageLabel"
    openPanel.showsResizeIndicator = true
    openPanel.showsHiddenFiles = false
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
    //openPanel.allowedFileTypes = allowedImageTypes
    openPanel.allowedContentTypes = [.png]
//  openPanel
    //----- Perform the selection dialog    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    guard openPanel.runModal() == .OK else { return nil }
    return openPanel.url?.path
```

Comment: Note that `allowedFileTypes` is deprecated in 12.0.

Comment: Solved problem. I knew that it is deprecated (see Question). I had to import "IniformTypeIdentifiers"

Comment: The correct name of importer is: import UniformTypeIdentifiers